# Why am I getting the error Incorrect syntax near 'BYStock_Date'?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I am getting above error in this query.

```
string query3 = "select Stock_Price,Stock_Quan_Met from Stock where Item_Id=(select ItemTileId from ItemTiles where ItemName=@itm) ORDER BY"+
            "Stock_Date ASC";
```

Comment: You need a space between ORDER BY and Stock_Date ASC: `+ " Stock_Date ASC"`

Comment: I saw a problem with the subquery: `...where Item_Id=(select ItemTileId from ItemTiles where ItemName=@itm...`. Do you have an UNIQUE index on `ItemName` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query results in

```
select Stock_Price,Stock_Quan_Met from Stock where Item_Id=(select ItemTileId from ItemTiles where ItemName=@itm) ORDER BYStock_Date ASC
```

Add a space at least and you fine.

```
string query3 = "select Stock_Price,Stock_Quan_Met from Stock where Item_Id=(select ItemTileId from ItemTiles where ItemName=@itm) ORDER BY "+
            "Stock_Date ASC";
```